# Need help applying animation in transform group in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, storyboard

I have a piece of xaml that applies a scale transform and a rotatetransform.

```
        <Image.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <RotateTransform Angle="0" x:Name="RotateTransform"/>
                <TranslateTransform X="0" Y="0"/>
                <ScaleTransform ScaleX="2" ScaleY="2"/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </Image.RenderTransform>
```

I also have a storyboard that needs to accesss RotateTransform like so:

```
        <Storyboard x:Key="Storyboard"
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)"
                Storyboard.TargetName="RotateTransform">
        <DoubleAnimation From="0" To="360" RepeatBehavior="Forever" SpeedRatio="0.25" />
    </Storyboard>
```

However I can not get the image to rotate, but it does scale up. Does anyone have suggestions to fix the problem?

Edit: I did figure out that i can use

```
    <Storyboard x:Key="Storyboard"
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Image.RenderTransform).Children[0].Angle"
                Storyboard.TargetName="ContentImage">
        <DoubleAnimation From="0" To="360" RepeatBehavior="Forever" SpeedRatio="0.25" />
    </Storyboard>
```

And call the animation by the array position, but why is it not possible to actually call the transform property's angle property automatically by x:Name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A RotateTransform does not have `RenderTransform` property, so you can't animate `RenderTransform.Angle`.

The animation would have to target the `Angle` property directly. Moreover, you would usually apply the `TargetName` and `TargetProperty` properties to the DoubleAnimation, not to the Storyboard. You would also set the `Duration` of the animation instead of applying a `SpeedRatio` for the default duration of one second.

```
<Storyboard>
    <DoubleAnimation
        Storyboard.TargetName="RotateTransform"
        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle"
        From="0" To="360" RepeatBehavior="Forever" Duration="0:0:4"/>
</Storyboard>
```

Comment: I've tried understanding how speed ratio works, but how exactly does it work? Does it base the speed of  a regular default speed, the clcok speed, the frame rate? I can not figure it out

Comment: From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.timeline.speedratio.aspx): *the rate at which time progresses for this timeline, relative to the speed of the timeline's parent or, if this is a root timeline, the default timeline speed*.

Answer (score 0):

The RenderTransform and RotateTransform are associated properties and need parenthesis around them. This is the correct syntax.

```
<Storyboard x:Key="Storyboard"
            TargetProperty="(RenderTransform).Children[0].(RotateTransform.Angle)"
            TargetName="ContentImage">
    <DoubleAnimation From="0" To="360" RepeatBehavior="Forever" SpeedRatio="0.25" />
</Storyboard>
```

as you pointed out in your edit you could also write this as

```
<Storyboard x:Key="Storyboard"
            TargetProperty="(RenderTransform).Children[0].Angle"
            TargetName="ContentImage">
    <DoubleAnimation From="0" To="360" RepeatBehavior="Forever" SpeedRatio="0.25" />
</Storyboard>
```